# How to confirm this user-agent string Chrome 25+ on more expensive Android devices?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, user-agent

I have a budget tablet, because I only use it for site testing, and I thought it was a good idea to check whether the sites also render correctly on budget tablets. It runs on Android OS 4.1.1. The user-agent string of Google Chrome 25, in its default setting ('Request desktop version' not ticked) is this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B367 Safari/531.21.10
```

Could anyone confirm that this is the same on more expensive Android devices (phones and tablets) such as Samsung? You can test this easily [here](http://conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/client-info.php). I find it strange that Chrome dropped the words `Chrome` and `Android`, compared to what I read about the string of Chrome Mobile 18.

The reason I need it is this. Android OS has only three fonts installed: Droid Sans, Droid Serif and Droid Monospace Sans. Not even Verdana, the most pleasant font for screens. And to have Verdana bold, italic and bold+italic rendered as well, for most browsers all 4 webfont files have to be loaded (only Firefox mobile seems able to do it with just the standard file).

Apple devices have all the web-safe fonts installed. Targeting browsers on Android devices to download the webfont files was easy, but now seems no longer possible when it comes to Chrome. However, before I send a complaint to Google, I want to be sure it is a generic thing of mobile Chrome versions as of v. 25, not just a thing on my budget tablet.

I am absolutely sure I'm not mistaking. I bought the tablet, a Cresta Android ([see here](https://www.kijkshop.nl/product/137164/cresta-tablet-ctp828/)) two weeks ago. When I switched it on and connected it to the net, it updated itself. And when I later had some problems with the fonts on my websites I checked its UA string with the PHP browser sniffer I had put online. With the result as described, and of which I now made a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot userAgent string Chrome on Cresta Android]

This is the string I get when I tick 'Request desktop version':

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.169 Safari/537.22
```

And what makes it even stranger is this. The device offers to have updates removed. I just did that for Chrome, and rechecked. While the desktop version string changes, to v. 18 and a few other digit changes, the string in its default mobile setting stays exactly the same. Not one digit, number or letter, changes from what I posted originally!

I cannot remove it entirely, so re-installing is not an option. And even if it would be, other folks with such a device won't know that there is something wrong with their Chrome version.

Comment: That UserAgent is not from a standard Chrome browser, that user agent string looks like it's taken from an iPad 1G (7B367) running iOS 3.2. A correctly formatted UserAgent for a newer Chrome browser looks like this `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; Nexus S Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.58 Mobile Safari/537.31`

Comment: @chrkad Thanks for the info. See the update of my original post. Your info does ease my mind, because I would rather have that this is a device-related matter than a new Chrome user-agent policy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutley sure that this is actually what is happening.  We never report iPad or Safari unless you have changed it via Devtools when testing.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. I am absolutely sure I'm not mistaking, and I haven't manipulated anything; see the update of my original post. You wrote: "We". Do you work for Google (that would be great)?

Comment: Could you confirm that you are working on it, or should I write to Google Headquarters?

Comment: How about downloading `Chrome Beta` from the Play store and check it, if it returns the correct UA, you can be sure that the manufacturer somehow has hacked the Chrome browser shipped with the device.

Comment: It looks like the manufacturer has overrided the UserAgent, or you have an app such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appo2.ua&hl=en installed.

Answer (score 0):

my tablet's chrome reports similiar - it has been updated a few times from the google play store, and it still pretends to be an ipad - this is a real problem for webdevelopers like me, the exact string is the same as yours:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B367 Safari/531.21.10
```